# Как сделать, чтобы выводилась только определенное число цифр после запятой?

Tags: c++

Например, у меня сейчас выдается: 17,765, а я хочу чтобы выдавалось 17,7 или 17,76. Как сделать?

Comment: [смотрите здесь](http://www.arachnoid.com/cpptutor/student3.html)

Answer (score 12):

*В стиле Си*

```
printf ("%.2f\n", val);

printf ("%.1f\n", val);
```

*В стиле С++*

```
cout << fixed;

cout.precision(2);

cout << val << endl;
```

Comment: какой заголовочный файл подключить к precision?

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << fixed;
cout.precision(2);
cout << val << endl;
```

Важно: `precision` делает округление по правилам математики.

Comment: А что такое «по правилам математики»?

Answer (score 1):

```
//я не пам’ятаю як це зробити у стилі С++, але у стилі С це робиться дуже легко
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
double pi = 3.14159;
printf("%.2f", pi);
//результатом буде такий вівід: 3.14
return 0;
}
```