# Как задать количество знаков после запятой для конкретной переменной c++

Tags: c++, типы-данных, числа

Имеется три переменные типа `double`. Нужно для первой переменной `t` сделать 1 знак после запятой, а для двух оставшихся `x` и `y` сделать 3 знака после запятой. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `printf` с соответствующими спецификаторами, `setprecision` для `ostream` C++...

Comment: Или явный ROUND при каждом присвоении, если надо вести вычисления с этой заданной точностью... как вариант, сделать переменную объектом, самокругляющимся при присвоении.

Comment: Вот тут есть похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/63900/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `setprecision()`:

```cpp
#include<iomanip>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x = 1.11111, y = 1.11111, t = 1.11111;
    cout << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(1) << t << " " << setprecision(3) << x << " " << y;
}
```

`setprecision()` устанавливает кол-во знаков после запятой.

`cout << fixed` вначале делает так, чтобы `setprecision()` устанавливало именно кол-во знаков после запятой, а не кол-во всех цифр числа.